# Getting 401 status code while hitting post url in angular2

Tags: angular, post, authorization

I am working on Angular2.I have a login url with which i have to do post operation.In Postman i am getting response from url. But In code when i am trying i am getting **401 status** code and error is **Invalid user credentials in authorization header**.
But I am giving correct user credentials in header.

```
 public getData(data: string) : Promise<any> {


     if(typeof(this.login_data) === "undefined") {
       let headers = new Headers();
       headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(this.username + ":" + this.password));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Accept", "application/json");

        headers.append("id", this.custid);

         let rOptions = new RequestOptions({

               headers: headers,
               body : data
             });
         return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, rOptions)
             .toPromise()
             .then(res => {
                           this.login_data = res.json().response;
                           return this.login_data;
             })
             .catch(this.handleError);

      } else {
          return Promise.resolve(this.login_data);
      }
}
```

getData method is there in my service class.to call that method am using below code.

```
 this.service.getData(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
         .then((response: Response) => {

             if (response.status === 200){
              //if success do next
             } 

         }).catch( error => {

           this.error_message = error.error;

           console.log("error in component and error is: " + JSON.stringify(error));
         } );
```

And in the requestbody i am passing this.

```
 let requestBody = {};
       let request = {};

       request['username'] = this.user.username;
       request['password'] = this.user.password;
       request['id'] = this.custid;


       requestBody['request'] = request;
```

Can anyone please help me with this.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are sending the wrong information here in the header while appending. please check with your backend side

```
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(this.username + ":" + this.password));
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.append("username", this.username);
        headers.append("password", this.password);
        headers.append("id", this.custid);

         let rOptions = new RequestOptions({

               headers: headers,
               body : JSON.stringify(data)
             });
```

Comment: Whatever infos are required i am sending those.@Pardeep

Comment: i don't think so because generally username and password are send using body part not in Header section.

Comment: Yeah checked with backend side,now edited the questions and not sending username and password still getting same 401 error.I have doubt whether the way i am sending request body is proper or not.@Pardeep

Comment: check my Update, you need to send `JSON.stringify` in case of body

Comment: Yeah tried that also JSON.stringify(data) still getting the same error.@Pardeep

Comment: remove this line also `headers.append("Accept", "application/json");`

Comment: Removed headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
Still getting same error .:( @Pardeep

Comment: sorry i am not able to check error like this, kindly reproduce your error on plunker.